# SSRS - Page Footer Items Moving

Tags: html, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report where by the page footer data appears on a pre formatted cheque paper. Therefore, the text box positioning of the footer items cannot change.

The problem is that in my report body I have a tablix. When the row count causes the report to display across more than 1 page, the footer data moves down about half an inch.

I've set the report header to appear only on the first page, and the report footer to appear only on the last page.

Does anybody know of a way to stop this shifting of footer data?
(The first image shows the footer rendered correctly when report on 1 page.
 The second image shows the footer data moving  down off the page when the report is more than 1 page)

[image: Correct positioning]

[image: Incorrect Positioning when report more than 1 page]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of the report designer view and the report preview?

Comment: Done. Second image shows the report footer text boxes moving off the page when report is more than 1 page,

Comment: Thanks for the preview images.  That helps.  Can you post a design view image as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Issue was the average price expression in the footer wasn't rounded, pushing the text box down, and with it the rest of the footer data down.

Comment: Well done!  You should accept your own answer if possible so that the question is closed.